# Square Store Administration Application Issue

Tags: web-services, google-chrome, testing, square

Square's store administration portal is on the fritz. The [error](https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/Questions-How-To/Store-Administration-Application-Issues/m-p/7511#M4086) occurs when navigating from "/store/admin/selector" to an individual location "/store/admin/". [error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRmY1.jpg)

Is there something beyond "be patience this is a fairly new freemium Saas" to be aware of?

Environment: Win 8.1, Chrome v51

Comment: update: error occurred again, 6/21 1:30 PM

Comment: update: uploading documents during account verification process seems to continuously attempt to upload. restarted process twice. .pdf size 309 KB